# Azure End-To-End transaction alert when total transaction time exceeds value

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

I have question regarding if it is possible in azure to make an alert if a End-To-End transaction duration exceeds a certain value like 30 sec. I can clearly see if a end-to-end transaction take longer then 30 sec in application insights. But I can't figure out how to make an alert that notifies me if any transacation exceeds a certain amount.

[End-To-End transaction example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pBT3.png)

If anyone knows how to do this let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If by and end-to-end transaction you mean the timespan of a request as shown in the screenshot you can simply create an alert based on the request duration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No I don't mean the time span of the request, I'm refering to the entire duration of the transaction including things that got published over the service bus. I can see them in application insight and it shows me how long everyting took til it was done but I can't find a way to set a trigger on that duration.

Comment: Thing is, you need to know when the whole transaction has ended. Is there a distinct event that can be used as a marker that the operation has ended?

Comment: Unfortunately not since it's dependant on how fast each micro service consumes its messages and that can differ with each request that ends up publishing messages. But application insights clearly can display when the entire transaction ended.

Comment: It does that based on the operation id. What you so is all telemetry with a given operation id. Let's say you view e2e transaction while it is still in progress you will see additional telemetry when you refresh the page. So unless there is some event that can be marked as the last event it will be difficult to have an alert as soon as an operation takes longer than xxx seconds.

Comment: Most likely you have non-span telemetry (custom events, logs) stamped with the same operationId which are not shown in this view but do impact this time range. Can you open a bottom panel on this view (there is a big blue button there) and examine it?

Comment: Hey this is probably true, We have for some end to end transactions ~190 calls ~31 events.